# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is my SchedulingStarter

```
 @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableScheduling
    @Import({SchedulingConfig.class})
    @EnableConfigurationProperties({ScheduleQueryProperties.class, ScheduleThreadPoolProperties.class,
            ScheduleUnblockMaintenceLimitQueryProperties.class, ScheduleUnblockMaintenceLimitThreadPool.class})
    public class SchedulingStarter {
    
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedulingStarter.class);
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            try {
                SSLUtil.turnOffSslChecking();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            SpringApplication.run(SchedulingStarter.class, args);
        }
    }
```

and this is the class that contains the method annotated with     @Scheduled(cron = "${schedule.account.unblock.process-time}")

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class LimitMaintenceFlowSchedule {

    @Autowired
    private LimitMaintenceFlowScheduleService limitMaintenceFlowScheduleService;

    @LogProfiler
    @LogInfo(logResult = true)
    @Scheduled(cron = "${schedule.account.unblock.process-time}")
    @Trace(dispatcher = true)
    public void executeToProcess() {
        log.info("m=execute, msg=Iniciando job de consulta ao manager para mudança de status");
        this.limitMaintenceFlowScheduleService.processLimitMaintenceFlow();
    }

}
```

I'm using this **bootstrap.yml** file for my tests

```
schedule:
  account:
    overlimit:
      process-time: "0 0 4 ? * *"
      process-error-time: "0 0 4 ? * *"
    unblock:
      process-time: "0 0 4 ? * *"
      process-error-time: "0 0 4 ? * *"
      thread-pool:
        name-prefix: schedule-job-executor
        core-pool-size: 1
        max-pool-size: 2
        queue-capacity: 1
        use-max-available-processors: false
      query:
        limit-size: 100
        execution-count: 3
        execute-until-end: true
```

stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'limitMaintenceFlowSchedule' defined in file [/home/emanzini/IdeaProjects/cards/credit-card-utils/scheduling/build/classes/java/main/ps/card/utils/scheduling/schedule/LimitMaintenceFlowSchedule.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'executeToProcess': Could not resolve placeholder 'schedule.account.unblock.process-time' in value "${schedule.account.unblock.process-time}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at ps.card.utils.scheduling.SchedulingStarter.main(SchedulingStarter.java:39) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'executeToProcess': Could not resolve placeholder 'schedule.account.unblock.process-time' in value "${schedule.account.unblock.process-time}"
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processScheduled(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$null$1(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:359) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$2(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:359) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:358) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:429) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put the configuration in a file called application.yml